# Include errors with pjsip as static library in Android NDK project

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Based on the two libs example I have a built pjsip as a static a static lib. So far so good. But when I just include one file from the lib in a file outside the library I get many errors.

EDIT: It is an Eclipse project, using Android.mk
I tried adding to Android.mk:

```
FILE_LIST_H := $(filter %.h*, $(ALLFILES))
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(FILE_LIST_H:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

Demo.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <pjsip/include/pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
```

Output

Compile++ thumb  : Demo <= Demo.cpp

In file included from C:/workspace/Demo/jni/Demo.cpp:3:

pjsua.h:30:19: error: pjsip.h: No such file or directory

pjsua.h:33:21: error: pjmedia.h: No such file or directory

pjsua.h:36:27: error: pjmedia-codec.h: No such file or directory

and it goes like this...

Please advice, 10XS,

Nir

Answer (score 0):

Add the pjsip include directory to the compiler call with `-I<location of the pjsip include folder>`. Since you haven't mentioned if you are using an IDE or just a makefile it is hard to give a more specific advice. If you are using an Android `.mk` file, add `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=<path to your pjsip include folder>` to it.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question based on your remarks. the -I flag didn't work :(

Comment: @nmnir you seem to have misunderstood me, of course it won't work since the fragment you posted does not have the pjsip include path anywhere. Where is the library you built located?

Comment: The pjsip is located under jni and it builds. To make it more simple I changed it to jni/mypjlib and added a flag -Imypjlib . I know this is not the usual way but it worked for me before with other libs instead of messing up with config scripts.

Comment: @nmnir, well I could be wrong but `-Imyjplib` also does not qualify as valid include path, you should at least do `-I./myjplib` (if the folder is in the same directory where the `.mk` file is, otherwise fix it to be a proper realtive path to the right location), and I guess that the include files are in `myjplib/include` or even deeper right? You must provide the path to the exact folder there header files are, not a top level folder. That is why you haven't succeeded so far:)

Comment: Thanks. the -I is the right way. need to be relative and add it for each include folder.

Comment: @nmnir yes. Sorry if I didn't express clearly enough the first time, I thought you were aware of this:) So the answer i correct then?